# How to use beautiful soup to return data inside specified tags and separated by delimited?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is how the data looks in html format.

```
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of IR</h4><p>Diane PHILIPS</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of Finance</h4><p>Nancy LOPEZ</p></div>,
 <div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of HR</h4><p>George SANTOZ</p></div>
```

I used the below code to extract the text.

```
for leader_list in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'leader-info'}):
print(leader_list.get_text())
```

This is what I get.

```
Director of IRDiane PHILIPS
Director of FinanceNancy LOPEZ
Director of HRGeorge SANTOZ
```

My question is how to place a pipe delimited in between "h4" and "p" tag texts?

```
Director of IR|Diane PHILIPS
Director of Finance|Nancy LOPEZ
Director of HR|George SANTOZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get_text()` with `separator=` parameter:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''\
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of IR</h4><p>Diane PHILIPS</p></div>
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of Finance</h4><p>Nancy LOPEZ</p></div>
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of HR</h4><p>George SANTOZ</p></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.select('.leader-info'):
    print(i.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
```

Prints:

```
Director of IR|Diane PHILIPS
Director of Finance|Nancy LOPEZ
Director of HR|George SANTOZ
```